# HTTP basic authentication to API endpoint for PUT request

Tags: services

I'm make a PUT request to a Drupal API end point created via a custom module and have enabled HTTP based authentication. When I call the api via rest client using Authorization header, the username and password prompts keeps coming again and again even though I supply a valid Drupal user. I see unauthorized user error as well using the advanced rest client on chrome. How do I solve it?

This is the code I am using.

```
function anonymize_user_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'update' => array(
      'update' => array(
        'help' => 'When user is deleted  users info should be anonymized',
        'callback' => 'anonymize_user_info',
       // 'access callback' => 'anonymize_callback',
        'access arguments' => array('update anonymize_user'),
        'access arguments append' => FALSE,
        'args' => array(
            array(
               'name' => 'id',
               'type' => 'int',
               'description' => 'The id of the user to update',
               'source' => array('path' => '0'),
               'optional' => FALSE,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

/**
* Implements hook_permission()
*/
function anonymize_user_permission() {
  return array(
    'update anonymize_user' => array(
      'title' => t('Update inactive user and anonymize'),
      'description' => t('Perform rest call to update and anonymize inactive user'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could supply some relevant code. Did you enable basic_auth in your custom service? You can do so via REST UI module (https://www.drupal.org/project/restui).

Answer (score 0):

The apache server needed to know the HTTP authorization header so the htaccess file had to be modified to accept the HTTP authorization header.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```